# Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I'm getting the error below. My problem is **NOT** with the actual error but the fact that it is saying that the error was **Uncaught**. If you take a look at my `auth.service.ts` and `sign-in.component.ts` files I am catching the error.

My question is, why am getting the *Error: Uncaught (in promise)* error in the console? What am I missing?

I'm using 
`"@angular/fire": "^7.0.4"` 
`"firebase": "^9.0.2"` 
`"rxjs": "6.6.7"`

[image]

auth.service.ts

```
    /**
     * Sign in
     *
     * @param credentials
     */
    signIn(credentials: { email: string; password: string }): Promise<any> 
    {
        return this.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(credentials.email, credentials.password)
            .then((userCredential) => {
                
                // Signed in 
                const user = userCredential.user;
                //console.log(user);

                // Store the access token in the local storage
                userCredential.user.getIdToken().then(token => {
                    this.accessToken = token;
                    //console.log(token);
                })

                // Set the authenticated flag to true
                this._authenticated = true;

                // Store the user on the user service
                //this._userService.user = user;

                // ...
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                const errorCode = error.code;
                const errorMessage = error.message;
                console.log('Show Error', error.code);
                throw errorCode;
            });
    }
```

sign-in.component.ts

```
    /**
     * Sign in
     */
    signIn(): void
    {
        // Return if the form is invalid
        if ( this.signInForm.invalid )
        {
            return;
        }

        // Disable the form
        this.signInForm.disable();

        // Hide the alert
        this.showAlert = false;

        // Sign in
        this._authService.signIn(this.signInForm.value)
            .then(
                () => {

                    // Set the redirect url.
                    // The '/signed-in-redirect' is a dummy url to catch the request and redirect the user
                    // to the correct page after a successful sign in. This way, that url can be set via
                    // routing file and we don't have to touch here.
                    const redirectURL = this._activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('redirectURL') || '/signed-in-redirect';

                    // Navigate to the redirect url
                    this._router.navigateByUrl(redirectURL);

                },
                (response) => {

                    console.log('error from auth.service', response);

                    // Re-enable the form
                    this.signInForm.enable();

                    // Reset the form
                    this.signInNgForm.resetForm();

                    // Set the alert
                    this.alert = {
                        type   : 'error',
                        message: 'Wrong email or password'
                    };

                    // Show the alert
                    this.showAlert = true;
                }
            );
    }
```

Comment: You're rethrowing the error again `throw errorCode;`, and I don't see code that handles that rethrow at first glance.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but how can I fix it?

Comment: Not rethrowing it would be one option. The other would be to catch the rethrown error higher in the callstack, and handle it there without rethrowing it.

Comment: I removed the rethrowing and the error is not being returned to the ```sign-in.component.ts```. The console still shows the firebase error.

Comment: Could you show me in code how to handle please? I would greatly appreciate it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, my native language is not English, so if I write like a fool you know why.

try this:

**_authService.service.ts**

```
    import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword, Auth, inMemoryPersistence, browserLocalPersistence } from '@angular/fire/auth';


    constructor(private _fireAuth: Auth,) {

/**
 * Sign-in
 *
 * @param credentials
 * @param rememberMe
 */
    async signIn(credentials: { email: string; password: string }, rememberMe: boolean): Promise<any> {
        // firebase Persistence.LOCAL   browserLocalPersistence
        // firebase Persistence.SESSION browserSessionPersistence
        // firebase Persistence.NONE    inMemoryPersistence

        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            //Initialize auth()
            const auth = getAuth();

            // Extra function
            if (rememberMe) {
                await getAuth().setPersistence(browserLocalPersistence).catch(error => reject(-1));
            } else {
                await getAuth().setPersistence(inMemoryPersistence).catch(error => reject(-1));
            }

            signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, credentials.email, credentials.password).then(async (userCredential) => {
                // Signed in 
                const user = userCredential.user;
                console.log(user);

                // Store the access token in the local storage
                await userCredential.user.getIdTokenResult().then(token => {
                    this.accessToken = token.token;
                    console.log(token);
                })

                // Set the authenticated flag to true
                this._authenticated = true;
            }).catch(error => reject(error.code));
        });
    }
```

**Note:** As you can see I have added some extra functions that you can remove if you are not interested (setPersistence), this allows you to take into account the user's choice to stay logged in if he wants to, or to remove his login when he closes the tab.

**sign-in.component.ts**

```
alert = {
        userNotFound : false,
        wrongPassword: false,
        unknownError : false,
};
    /**
     * Sign in
     */
    signIn(): void
    {
        // Return if the form is invalid
        if ( this.signInForm.invalid )
        {
            return;
    }

    // Disable the form
    this.signInForm.disable();

    // Hide the alert
    this.showAlert = false;

    // Sign in
    this._authService.signIn(this.signInForm.value)
        .then(
            () => {

                // Set the redirect url.
                // The '/signed-in-redirect' is a dummy url to catch the request and redirect the user
                // to the correct page after a successful sign in. This way, that url can be set via
                // routing file and we don't have to touch here.
                const redirectURL = this._activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('redirectURL') || '/signed-in-redirect';

                // Navigate to the redirect url
                this._router.navigateByUrl(redirectURL);

            },
            (response) => {

                console.log('error from auth.service', response);

                // Re-enable the form
                this.signInForm.enable();

                // Reset the form
                this.signInNgForm.resetForm();

                // Set the alert
                if (error === - 1) {
                this.alert.unknownError = true;
                } else if (error === 'auth/email-not-found' || error === 'auth/user-not-found') {
                this.alert.userNotFound = true;
                } else if (error === 'auth/wrong-password') {
                this.alert.wrongPassword = true;
                }
            }
        );
}
```

Comment: there are several errors in your code sample but after I fixed those, it works like a charm. Thank you sir!!!

Comment: @LuisCabrera Please could you tell me where the errors are, because I more or less use this form.

Comment: 1) in _authService.service.ts you are expecting 2 parameters but only passing one in sing-in.component.ts
2) I was not able to use the alert object you created

Comment: 3) in _authService.service.ts I added resolve(this._authenticated) to return the call to the component

Comment: Ah I saw it, it's just that as in my code I use the 2 values, I didn't realize, but well, good that it worked for you, if you have more questions about the Angular Fire module let me know, because there is not much updated documentation, good luck my friend.

Comment: the important thing that worked for me here was adding ... const auth = getAuth() ... and ... signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, credentials.email, credentials.password) ... the wrapper Promise was not needed

Answer (score 4):

For me, explicitly `catch`ing the error as in the above answers still resulted in the error being sent to the console as `Uncaught (in Promise)`. For whatever reason, in addition to sending the error to be caught via `Promise.catch`, Angular was routing the error through its default [ErrorHandler](https://angular.io/api/core/ErrorHandler) and claiming that the error was uncaught. I had to override the default ErrorHandler with my own, detect that these were [FirebaseErrors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.app.firebaseerror?hl=en) and then ignore them (since I already had an explicit `Promise.catch` defined where I needed it).

Some tips in case they are helpful:

1. Angular only recognizes error handlers defined on the *root* module. Definitions on *child* modules seem to be ignored. You get one global error handler that needs to do everything.
2. The core FirebaseErrors seem to be stored in a `rejection` property on the main `error` object. You can detect them like so:

```
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { FirebaseError } from "firebase/app";

interface AngularFireError extends Error {
    rejection: FirebaseError;
}

function errorIsAngularFireError(err: any): err is AngularFireError {
    return err.rejection && err.rejection.name === 'FirebaseError';
}

// Not providedIn 'root': needs special handling in app.module to override default error handler.
@Injectable()
export class YourErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    handleError(error: any) {
        // AngularFire errors should be catchable and handled in components; no need to further process them.
        if (!errorIsAngularFireError(error)) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }
}
```

And in your root module:

```
providers: [
    ...,
    { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: YourErrorHandler }
  ],
```

Answer (score 1):

as Frank mentionned you are throwing an error without catching it back at a higher lever what I would try would be to do as so:

```
try {
  this._authService.signIn(this.signInForm.value)
            .then(
                () => {

                    // Set the redirect url.
                    // The '/signed-in-redirect' is a dummy url to catch the request and redirect the user
                    // to the correct page after a successful sign in. This way, that url can be set via
                    // routing file and we don't have to touch here.
                    const redirectURL = this._activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('redirectURL') || '/signed-in-redirect';

                    // Navigate to the redirect url
                    this._router.navigateByUrl(redirectURL);

                },
                (response) => {

                    console.log('error from auth.service', response);

                    // Re-enable the form
                    this.signInForm.enable();

                    // Reset the form
                    this.signInNgForm.resetForm();

                    // Set the alert
                    this.alert = {
                        type   : 'error',
                        message: 'Wrong email or password'
                    };

                    // Show the alert
                    this.showAlert = true;
                }
            );
} catch(e) {}
```

just surround your code with a `try catch` block so the error is muted. I didn't tested it but maybe calling another `catch` method after `then` could do the trick still it would be at the same level (Promise level) so I'm not sure it would work.

Comment: thank you for the suggestions. I tried adding the ```try catch``` as you suggested but got the same results. I then tried another ```catch``` method after ```then``` but got the same thing again. Other ideas?

Comment: UPDATE. I tried adding both the ```try catch``` and the additional ```catch``` after ```then``` but didn't work either

Comment: @LuisCabrera are you sure you haven't changed code in the meantime?

Comment: @LuisCabrera could you create a stackblitz to reproduce the error please?